# Trigger Compilation Error, Oracle 11g

Tags: triggers, oracle11g

Banging my head up against this one for a while. I'm constructing a database on oracle 11g, and am attempting to insert a record into a "registry" table whenever a record is created on a "data product" table. The registry table needs to auto-increment the product_id, and then that product_id is used as a foreign key on the data product table. Here is my trigger code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TR_CAMERA_DP_DPR_CREATE"
BEFORE INSERT ON "DD1"."CAMERA_DP"
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.product_id := ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL;

  insert into dd1.dp_registry
         (    product_id,
              fs_location,
              parent_group_id,
              product_name,
              shortdes,
              createdate,
              revision )
         values
         (    :new.product_id,
              'placeholder',
              0,
              '_image',
              'description placeholder',
              sysdate,
              0
          );

END;
```

So, ideally, an insert into dd1.camera_dp without providing a product_id will first insert a record into dd1.dp_registry, and then use that incremented product_id as the key field for dd1.camera_dp.

The insert statement works when run with a hard-coded value for :new.product_id, and ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL is also working properly. I get the feeling I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the compilation error that you're seeing?

Comment: I'm not getting any compilation errors, just that ORA-04098 trigger is invalid and failed re-validation when I attempt to insert.

Comment: when I select from user_errors, it tells me that table or view does not exist.... but if I copy the insert statement out of my code, and execute that sql (with a value replaced for :new.product_id) I get no error.

Comment: That strongly implies that you're getting an error when you create the trigger.  If you are using SQL*Plus, type `show errors` after creating the trigger and getting the message that the object was created with errors to show the specific errors.  Or you can query `user_errors` to see the syntax errors associated with the object.

Comment: I'm wondering if it isn't possible to insert into another table using a :new value inside an insert trigger. I don't know why this would be, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works perfectly well for me.  If you're getting an error, there is something about the code that you are actually running from the code that you posted.

```
SQL> create table CAMERA_DP(
  2    product_id number,
  3    name varchar2(10)
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> create sequence id_seq;

Sequence created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create table dp_registry
  2           (    product_id number,
  3                fs_location varchar2(100),
  4                parent_group_id number,
  5                product_name varchar2(100),
  6                shortdes varchar2(100),
  7                createdate date,
  8*               revision number)
SQL> /

Table created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TR_CAMERA_DP_DPR_CREATE"
  2  BEFORE INSERT ON "CAMERA_DP"
  3  FOR EACH ROW
  4  BEGIN
  5    :new.product_id := ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
  6    insert into dp_registry
  7           (    product_id,
  8                fs_location,
  9                parent_group_id,
 10                product_name,
 11                shortdes,
 12                createdate,
 13                revision )
 14           values
 15           (    :new.product_id,
 16                'placeholder',
 17                0,
 18                '_image',
 19                'description placeholder',
 20                sysdate,
 21                0
 22            );
 23* END;
 24  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into camera_dp( name ) values( 'Foo' );

1 row created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1* select product_id from dp_registry
SQL> /

PRODUCT_ID
----------
         1
```

If you're getting an error that a table doesn't exist, the common culprits would be

- You actually have a typo in the name of your table
- You don't have permission to insert into the table.  Note that if in your actual code, not everything is in the same schema, my guess would be that the user that owns the trigger has privileges to `INSERT` into the `DP_REGISTRY` table via a role rather than via a direct grant.  Since priileges granted through a role are not available in a definer's rights stored procedure block, that would explain why you can do something at the command line but not in PL/SQL.

Comment: Thank you so much. You're probably right about the privileges. Going to tinker with them a bit and see what I find.

Comment: Thank you! That was the exact issue. As it turns out I was developing my database on a third party program (EDR Concepts) and then testing through sqlplus, and on two different IDs. The EDR Concepts user had more permissions than the user tables I was making, and was not defaulting "DD1" before my triggers.